# If a sequence is bounded on finite intervals and has a limit, then prove sequence is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Given sequence $x_n$ which satisfies $0\leq x_n\leq n$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=b$, can we say $x_n$ is bounded? (i.e., $sup_{n\geq 0}x_n$ is finite).

Here is my attempt: there exists $N$, such that for $n\geq N$,  $x_n\leq b+\epsilon$, and for $n<N$, $x_n<N$. Hence $x_n<\min\{N,b+\epsilon\}$, hence it is bounded. Is that okay?

Comment: A convergent sequence is always bounded.

Comment: @MartinR thank you!